# Android Activity call another Activity method

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

A TabActivity start other activity when i click on a tab,

How to send information to parent (tabActivity) and don't finish current activity?

My tabactivity start another activity like this :

> mTabHost.addTab(
>
> mTabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_OPTIONS)
>
> .setIndicator(TabImgFond5)
>
> .setContent(intentOptions));

Inside my new Activity Option, i would like to Call method of Tabactivity, is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `getParent()` from the tab's activity to get at the `TabActivity`.

Comment: Thanks it's working !


Onglets GestionnaireTab = (Onglets) this.getParent();


GestionnaireTab.setNbMessage(5);